# TravisCI maven deployment to OSSRH snapshots fail as unauthorized

Tags: deployment, maven-3, travis-ci

I did some research in the net and finally ended up with this setup for **.travis.yml**:

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk8
install: mvn install -B
before_script:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_ea1244aca28a_key -iv $encrypted_ea1244aca28a_iv -in codesigning/codesigning.asc.enc -out codesigning/codesigning.asc -d
- gpg --fast-import codesigning/codesigning.asc
script:
- mvn test -B
- if [ $TRAVIS_TEST_RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
  mvn deploy -B -P sign,build-extras --settings codesigning/mvnsettings.xml;
  fi
env:
  global:
    - secure: encrypted env-variable OSSRH_USER
    - secure: encrypted env-variable OSSRH_PASS
    - secure: encrypted env-variable GPG_KEY_NAME
    - secure: encrypted env-variable GPG_PASSPHRASE
```

the mentioned files in folder *codesigning* are in place

content of **mvnsettings.xml**

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <username>${env.OSSRH_USER}</username>
      <password>${env.OSSRH_PASS</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>gpg</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
        <gpg.keyname>${env.GPG_KEY_NAME}</gpg.keyname>
        <gpg.passphrase>${env.GPG_PASSPHRASE}</gpg.passphrase>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

A sample project is [com.sikulix.tigervnc](https://github.com/RaiMan/Sikulix2tigervnc)

I am sure, that the deployment works, since I tested with the same credentials and signing key locally with Jenkins (the stuff is on OSSRH).

If I run this setup on TravisCI, it fails when trying to upload to OSSRH with the error

```
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact
com.sikulix:sikulix2tigervnc:jar.asc:2.0.0-20170413.085320-8 
from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots):
Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sikulix/sikulix2tigervnc/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sikulix2tigervnc-2.0.0-20170413.085320-8.jar.asc.
Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

I made various tests with different setups and using the maven -X option and used *gpg -K* to check the key and *env* to check the actual environent - everything as it should be:

- OSSRH userid is decrypted correctly
- the password is not shown in the debug log, so I have to trust it is ok (does not contain any offending characters for bash), but is correct in environment variable
- the key is imported correctly
- in the signing step the key name and passphrase are correct

I even tried the Nexus staging plugin in various setups: no success.

Since I really want to switch completely to TravisCI with [SikuliX version 2](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX2) I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I someone stumbles over this question:

the solution:
the right brace in the  setting in the settings section is missing.

the solution works now